# pause in cmd \ Freeze and UnFreeze

Tags: c, cmd

I need a command in cmd that works like pause but I can code to continue.
e.g.

```
system("pause");
some lines of code;`
```

The problem with `system("pause")` is that "some lines of code" will not work until the user press sth.
I want to continue cmd with some command.

Comment: 1) if it needs to continue then in which way it works like `pause`?  Do you just want to execute some code in parallel? 2) Any attempt?

Comment: Why do you use `system("pause")` anyway? I see it a lot, but I don't get it, if you are learning c programming, you must find a c solution, and avoid using external programs as much as possible. The other one is worst `#include <conio.h>` and still do `system("cls");`

Comment: Yes, i want to execute code in parallel. @AdrianoRepetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want something that run the code but update cmd only when I give the
>   permission to it.

If I understand correctly, *the code* shall produce output which you don't want to be shown before you press a key. If you don't mind to have the output paged, you could use something like

```
        FILE *stream = popen("PAUSE<CON&&MORE", "w");
```

and let *the code* output to stream (with `fprintf(stream, ...)` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever use `system()` if you can avoid it. It's crude, error-prone, and non-portable.

C11 introduces threading support, including [thrd_sleep()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep). That should be your preferred solution (if supported by your compiler setup).

If your compiler vendor does **not** support C11, bugger him about it. That standard is almost four years old now.

Comment: My compiler doesn't support thrd_sleep().
But anyway thank you for your help:)

Comment: @Iman: That's not very surprising, seeing how you talked about `cmd` and `pause` -- Microsoft doesn't even support C99. But I thought I'd give the "right" answer before all the "working" ones float in. ;-)

Comment: If you're _limited_ to Windows environment and you want to EXECUTE some code in parallel (not merely waste CPU time waiting in pause) then take a look to [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not portable but it works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

WinAPI defines the [`Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
VOID WINAPI Sleep(
  _In_  DWORD dwMilliseconds
);
```

> This function causes a thread to relinquish the remainder of its time
>   slice and become unrunnable for an interval based on the value of
>   dwMilliseconds.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    Sleep( 5000 ); // pause execution for at least 5 seconds
    some_lines_of_code;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it stops running the rest of code.I want something that run the code but update cmd only when I give the permission to it.

Comment: @Iman: Voting to close the question as "unclear what you're asking", because `pause` or `sleep` quite obviously isn't it. You need to phrase more exactly what it is that you actually want, and at this point it'd be better to ask this in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a method to check if `stdin` contains data ready to read; you want to use some *non-blocking* or *asynchronous* I/O so that you can read input when it becomes available, and perform other tasks until then.

You won't find a whole heap about non-blocking/asynchronous I/O in standard C, but in POSIX C you can set `STDIN_FILENO` as non-blocking using `fcntl`. As an example, here's a program which prompts you to press enter (like `pause` does) and busy-loops, allowing your code to conduct other (preferably non-blocking) actions inside the loop while it waits for the keystroke (ahemm, byte, since `stdin` is technically a *file*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(void) {
    char c;
    puts("Press any key to continue...");
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);
    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, 1, &c) != 1 && errno == EAGAIN) {
        /* code in here will execute repeatedly until a key is struck or a byte is sent */
        errno = 0;
    }
    if (errno) {
        /* code down here will execute when an input error occurs */
    }
    else {
        /* code down here will execute when that precious byte is finally sent */
    }
}
```

That's non-blocking I/O. Other alternatives include using asynchronous I/O or extra threads. You should probably use non-blocking I/O or asynchronous I/O (i.e. `epoll` or `kqueue`) for this task in particular; using extra threads just to determine when a character is sent to `stdin` is likely a little bit too hefty.